# Creating a local folder through an url

Tags: windows, url, browser

**imagine you want to have a link on a website that creates a local folder and opens it in the Windows Explorer as soon as click on it.** Something like `<a href="new_file:///C:/folder/newfolder">Go to new folder</a>`

I know there is the file:-protocol, but this only opens a local folder. Is there a way to specify in the url that the browser should also create the folder.

It might be against lot's of security policies. **But I'm just curious if there is any way you could achieve that. What ever come in your mind? Don't hold back.**

Cheers,

Gerardo

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, this is not allowed for web pages from internet. (imagine a rogue script running thousands of these)

You may be able to open an existing folder, in the browser (not via Windows Explorer, unless it's IE and the page is trusted).

If you want to create a folder, try using [Offline Storage API](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage)s for HTML5. This may not accomplish the 'opening in Win Explorer' part, but you can store data on user's machine.

Hope this helps.